# How to use stream api to define Constraints rule such as this

Tags: stream, optaplanner

Multiple employees work together to complete a task. If the first employee can complete 70% of the task in his working time, the remaining 30% needs to be assigned to the second employee. How to use streamapi to define constraint rules and calculate the start time and end time of its task.

Answer (score 1):

Would it be possible to have two separate tasks instead, where the second one depends on the first one (and thus, it cannot start before the first task completes)?

The dependency between the two tasks can be implemented as a hard constraint.

Answer (score 1):

The first question is how to design the models you use for this. I assume you have a `Set<Task> tasks` that has a total required time to be completed by `Set<Employee> employees`? Then you may create `List<TaskAssignment>` that can aggregate a Set of employees to complete the task were each assigned employee can contribute by different parts. Depending on the complexity of how and when employees can work on a task can make it more challenging though but should be straightforward.